# How to enroll Macs on Profile Manager MDM using Terminal?

Tags: macos, profile-manager

I've been tweaking the command `profiles` quite sometime now but the -password parameter doesn't work. I've wanted to enroll machines using an MDM profile but it will require the user to input credentials via prompt which defeats our automation.

Additional: I can install Trust profiles from macOS server via terminal by simply executing `profiles -I -F  but not the MDM.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried to install the profile with root access. its getting install without password. but stuck at MDM profile which is very important. I have discuss with apple and they told me that you required DEP if you want automation.